# $cordovaFileTransfer não envia parametros para webservice?

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, apache-cordova

Estou tentando fazer o upload de uma imagem usando o `$cordovaFileTransfer`. Quando envio a imagem quero enviar tbm alguns parametros como o id do usuario, o problema é que esses parametros chegam nulos no webservice.
Fiz meu webservice em CakePHP e testando pelo **postman** do chrome consigo enviar normalmente os parametros por POST, ou seja, o webservice está funcionando.

Como consigo enviar parametros usando o $cordovaFileTransfer ?

**Controller**

```
/** add image profile  */
    function addImagemUsuario(){
        var img = document.getElementById('smallimage');
        var _pathFile = img.src;
        var _fileName = _pathFile.substr(_pathFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var _url = AppConstants.webServiceUrl + "/users/addImageUsuarioApp.json";
        var _headers2 = HeaderProvider2.getHeader();
        //options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();      
        options.chunkedMode = true;
        options.mimeType = 'image/jpg';
        options.fileKey = 'imageFile';
        options.headers = _headers2;
        options.fileName = _fileName;
        //parametros        
        options.params = {
            "idUsuario":"333",          
        };      

        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(_url, _pathFile, options, true).then(function (result) {
            console.log("Result: " + result);
             //console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
         }, function (err) {
            console.log("Erro: " + err);
             //console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
         }, function (progress) {
             // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
         });

    };
```

**header**

```
app.provider('HeaderProvider2', function(){
    var email = 'admin@admin.com.br';
    var senha = 'password'

    this.$get = function(Base64){
        return {
            getHeader: function(){
                return {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(email + ':' + senha),                 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' 
                }               
            }
        };
    };

});
```

**CakePHP webservice**

```
public function addImageUsuarioApp(){
            $this->autoRender = false;            
            $id = $this->request->data["idUsuario"];
            $imageFile = $_FILES["imageFile"];
            $retorno = array("id"=>$id, "image"=>$imageFile);

            return json_encode($retorno);
        }
```

**Retorno WebService**

```
Result: <pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa4db2-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa4db2-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Notice</b> (8)</a>: Undefined index: idUsuario [<b>APP\Controller\UsersController.php</b>, line <b>200</b>]<div id="cakeErr5654611fa4db2-trace" class="cake-stack-trace" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa4db2-code').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa4db2-code').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Code</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa4db2-context').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa4db2-context').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Context</a><pre id="cakeErr5654611fa4db2-code" class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">public&nbsp;function&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">addImageUsuarioApp</span><span style="color: #007700">(){
</span></span></code>
<code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">autoRender&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">false</span><span style="color: #007700">;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></code>
<span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$id&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">request</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">data</span><span style="color: #007700">[</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"idUsuario"</span><span style="color: #007700">];
</span></span></code></span></pre><pre class="stack-trace">UsersController::addImageUsuarioApp() - APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 200
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 490
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 193
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 167
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 115</pre></div></pre><pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa6523-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa6523-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Notice</b> (8)</a>: Undefined index: imageFile [<b>APP\Controller\UsersController.php</b>, line <b>201</b>]<div id="cakeErr5654611fa6523-trace" class="cake-stack-trace" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa6523-code').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa6523-code').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Code</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa6523-context').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5654611fa6523-context').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Context</a><pre id="cakeErr5654611fa6523-code" class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">autoRender&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">false</span><span style="color: #007700">;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span></code>
<code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$id&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">request</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">data</span><span style="color: #007700">[</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"idUsuario"</span><span style="color: #007700">];
</span></span></code>
<span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$imageFile&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$_FILES</span><span style="color: #007700">[</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"imageFile"</span><span style="color: #007700">];
</span></span></code></span></pre><pre id="cakeErr5654611fa6523-context" class="cake-context" style="display: none;">$id = null</pre><pre class="stack-trace">UsersController::addImageUsuarioApp() - APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 201
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 490
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 193
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 167
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 115</pre></div></pre>{"id":null,"image":null}
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja na hora de vc recuperar esses parametros no Cake, pq no lado do app parece estar certo.